# TypeError: cannot read property 'length' of undefined (defined by function parameter)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multidimensional-array, variable-length-array

I'm trying to make the simple code below works, but always got the following error: *TypeError: cannot read property 'length' of undefined*.

```
function multiplyAll(arr) {


     var product = 1;

      if (arr === undefined) {
        return "Undefined Array!";
      } else {


    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; i++) {
        product *= arr[i][j];
      }
    }
    return product;


     }
    }


    multiplyAll([[7,2],[6,4],[5,8,9]]);
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You are checking whether `arr` is undefined, but not whether `arr[i]` is undefined..

Comment: In fact, many ours a code make me blind. I was really incrementing `i` instead of `j` in the second for loop.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a copy&paste/typo error:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; i++)
```

In the inner for loop, you're incrementing `i` instead of `j`. You're going off the end of the array, making `arr[i]` undefined.

You could have solved this by monitoring the values of `i` and `j` using a debugger or calls to `console.log`. You would have noticed that `i` was incrementing too fast, while `j` remained at 0.